# Finding a length in a list for a specific criterion

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list as following:

```
l = {{"A", "b", "c", "d"}, {"A", "g", "x"}, {"b", "q", "r", 
"A"}, {"f", "t"}, {"A", "z"}}
```

I want to count the Length of those elements that they have `"A"`.
I have done as,

```
Map[Length, Table[Select[l[[i]], UpperCaseQ], {i, Length[l]}]]
```

this makes a table of those elements that have A and calculates the length, but what I am looking for is to have an outcome like:
`{4,3,4,2}` namely there is `A` in element with Length 4, 3, 4 and 2. How shall I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Length /@ Select[MemberQ["A"]] @ l
```

> {4, 3, 4, 2}

To get lengths of sublists that contain an uppercase letter:

```
Length /@ Select[MemberQ[_?UpperCaseQ]] @ l
```

> {4, 3, 4, 2}

Comment: Thank you @kglr. Is it possible to make this general, the real list I have has some capital strings of different names think of it as `"A"`, `"B"` and so on, so that's why I have used `UpperCaseQ` In other words, is there a way to do this without mentioning `"A"`? so it can scan all those entries that are capital?

Comment: @William, updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that (as always) @kglr has answered the question well. However to fully generalize the answer it seems like regular expressions might be useful. I found this surprisingly difficult. I convert OPs lists into strings, and then using Cases and StringMatchQ with the RegularExpression function. Seems clunky but allows for any sort of regex.

```
StringLength @ Cases[s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, 
    RegularExpression["([a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*)"]]][StringJoin[#] & /@ l]
```

If I were coding with the idea that someone else might someday look at it, I might skip the one-liner and do:

```
regS = "([a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*)";
sL = StringJoin[#] & /@ l;
sL = Cases[s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, RegularExpression[regS]]][sL];
StringLength @ sL
```

> {4, 3, 4, 2}